# AS3: How do I reference a Scene in code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animate-cc

I have objects in the main scene and I wish to reference them on a movie clip.

If it was the other way around, I could do

```
Movieclip.button_btn(...)
```

What is the equivalent to do that but with a Scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

For anyone trying to find it, it's Object(root). In this case it would be

```
Object(root).button_btn(...)
```